# Java date issue while storing and querying?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, datetime

I am using Java 1.7 and mysql database. mysql db is set to UTC timezone. I have below code to save the date into db.

While saving I am using

```
new java.util.Date()
```

If I want to search by Date range through UI, I have below code.

### Javascript file:

```
 var before = new Date();
 var after = new Date();
 before.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
 after.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

### Spring controller:

I get above dates in `milliseconds` and Date object is created out of milliseconds as below.

```
new Date(postCreatedBeforeInMillis);
new Date(postCreatedAfterInMillis);
```

Now If I send above date objects to database for `date range search`, will there be any issue while searching? because **mysql db is set to UTC but above dates are not in UTC**. Do I need to convert above dates to UTC to search against mysql db?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK `java.util.Date` has no timezone. By the way, why aren't you using Calendar instead?

Comment: If there is no timezone in util Date then will mysql store it in UTC format?

Comment: Well, it should, though I would definitely test it.

Comment: While querying, If i send util Date, will the date gets converted into UTC before querying against mysql? bcaz mysql dates are in UTC format.

Comment: Well, there should be no conversion really, becuse java.util.Data is basically in UTC.

Comment: It's probably a bit late, but if I were to start a new Java project, I would avoid java.util.Date like the plague! The new "javax.time" stuff is MUCH better in 1.8 (and there is a backport available for 1.7 also)